# Bootstrap navigation hamburger on symbol functionality

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, hamburger-menu

I have used Bootstrap menu, I cant seem to see why the hamburger drop-down in not functioning.

at the moment the full menu is expanded on mobile and the hamburger symbol has not functionality, im not sure what has gone wrong in the code

**Full code HTMl**

```
<nav class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container" style="height: 63px;">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bootstrap-navbar-collapse-1"
                aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand " href="<?php echo get_page_link(2); ?>">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/logo.png">
        </a>

        <button type="button" class="btn button-primary-signup navbar-btn navbar-right hidden-xs">
            Sign up
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="login-button btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-right hidden-xs">
            Login
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" style="background-color: #333;max-height: 44px;">
        <div class="container">
            <?php bootstrap_megamenu_nav(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**function php**

```
function bootstrap_megamenu_nav()
{
    wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'locations-primary',
            'depth' => 4,
            'container' => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id' => 'bootstrap-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav yamm navbar-main-head',
            'fallback_cb' => 'Yamm_Nav_Walker_menu_fallback',
            'walker' => new Yamm_Nav_Walker())
    );
}
```

Comment: have you added jQuery to your site [ http://jquery.com/ ]

Comment: yes I have, and inspected to see if file is there (as im using a CDN) but is there and working

Answer (score 0):

There is no target with `id="bootstrap-navbar-collapse-1"`.

The collapsible nav items are supposed to be contained in a `collapse` element.

See the Bootstrap docs for an example:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Comment: Good spot, but this is called in the php function